# Python transpose function only transpose 2 rows

Tags: python

I need help with transposing row to column using python.

I use this script to transpose a csv file :

```
import csv

data = zip(*csv.reader(open("lamp_headersimplified.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("lamp1.csv", "wb")).writerows(data)
```

I test it using a large .csv file that have >5000 row and different number of column for each row but the result is not like what I expected.

Example csv file :

```
a , 1 , 2 , 3 ,
b , 2 , 4 , 6 , 8
c , 3 , 6 ,   ,  
d , 4 ,
```

Result that I got :

```
a , b , c , d
1,  2 , 3 , 4
```

Result that I want :

```
a , b , c , d
1 , 2 , 3 , 4
2 , 4 , 6 
3 , 6 
    8
```

Is there anything that I need to add on the script?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pandas` you could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('lamp_headersimplified.csv', header=None)
df.transpose().to_csv('lamp1.csv', header = False, index=False)
```

with your input the following output `csv` it writes:

```
a,b,c,d 
1,2,3,4
2,4,6,
3,6, ,
 ,8, ,
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I get an error when I tried your script. The error is `pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 126 fields in line 2, saw 298`

Comment: oh, i guess then your csv file is not have same number of columns (commas) in all the rows. For example, first row may have 125 commas, while the second one is having 297 commas. Can you ensure all the lines to have same number of fields (the fields can be blank, it does not matter).

Comment: What do you mean by same number of fields? Is it same number of columns? My csv file did not have same number of columns.

Comment: what i mean to say is that like the example you provided, in the similar way, if your csv contains at least same number of commas in every line (the column values need not be present), it will work. If you open the csv with excel like tools and save it back it will save it in the same structure i think.

Comment: ah, yes....I got it work thanks to your advice. I re-save the csv file and there is no error after I run it. Thank you very much!